# Construindo um web crawler em python. Preciso de ajuda para adicionar threads

Tags: python, thread

Estou tentando desenvolver um web crawler para estudos. Ele está bem simples e gostaria de melhorá-lo. Como usar threads para acelerar/melhorar o processo? O programa poderia fazer vários links em paralelo. Como aplicar o conceito de threads ao crawler?

```
import requests
import re

to_crawl =['http://www.g1.globo.com'] #url para fazer o crawler (a semente: ponto de partida)
crawled = set()# o conjunto do que "ja fiz"/ja percorrido, foi feito o crawer
#se a url já estiver em crawled, vou para a próxima!

#é bom usar header pra finger ser um navegador
header = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0",
          "accept": "*/*",
          "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
          "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          }
while True: #executar pra sempre...

    url = to_crawl[0]
    try: #tratar pox ex URL invalidas..
        req = requests.get(url,headers=header)
    except: #remove a url
        to_crawl.remove(url)
        crawled.add(url)
        continue #passa pro prox link


    #print (req.text) #é a página!
    html = req.text



    links = re.findall(r'(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])' ,html)
    print ("Crawling", url)

    #apos a requisicao, removo do to_crawl e insiro em no conjunto crawled:
    to_crawl.remove(url)
    crawled.add(url)


    #agora joga links in to_crawl se nao estiverem em crawled:
    for link in links:
        if link not in crawled and link not in to_crawl:  #se nao estiver nas 2 listas
            to_crawl.append(link)


    #print(padrao.group())
    #print(padrao,)

    for link in links:
        print(link)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo (python 3.x) simples, a abordagem é um pouco diferente da sua:

```
import re
from threading import Thread
import requests

def get_links(url):
    req = get_req(url)
    if(req is not None):
        html = req.text
        urls = re.findall('(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', html)
        return urls
    return None

def get_req(url):
    try:
        req = s.get(url)
        return req
    except Exception:
        print('[-] Erro ao ir buscar página: ', url)
        return None

def inject_links(data, url):
    urls = get_links(url)
    if(urls is not None):
        for url in urls:
            if(url not in data and len(data) < urls_max):
                data.add(url) # adicionamos aos urls crawled
                print('[+] Total: {} [+] putting: {} '.format(len(data), url))
                return inject_links(data, url)
    return

def producer(url, threadNum):
    while len(data) < urls_max:
        inject_links(data, url)
    #print('\n', data) # comentar isto depois de ter percebido, este print e muito pesado 
    print('[+] Terminated - killing thread {} -> Total urls stored: {}'.format(threadNum, len(data)))
    # aqui pode escrever para um ficheiro por exemplo

data = set()
urls_max = 100
threads = 10
start_urls = ['http://pt.stackoverflow.com/', 'http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp', 'http://spectrum.ieee.org/']

s = requests.Session()
for i in range(len(start_urls)):
    for j in range(threads):
        t = Thread(target=producer, args=(start_urls[i], '{}.{}'.format(i+1, j+1)))
        t.start()
```

O uso de [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) é para aumentar a performance quando adicionamos/procuramos alguma coisa armazenada lá, e para evitar urls duplicados. Retire o comentário do print dentro do método `producer()` para ver os urls armazenados

Neste caso vamos começar em três links com 10 threads em cada um, e cada tread é 'morta' quando tivermos 100 links. Esta condição vai ser o core do termino do programa `if(url not in data and len(data) < urls_max)`, se o url não existir já dentro do nosso [set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) então adicionamos, e se numero total de urls no set for inferior ao `urls_max`

Comment: obrigado. Vou estudar o código!

Comment: criei um outro tópico com assunto semelhante num outro projeto, pois tenho dificuldade com o uso de Threads

Answer (score 2):

Montei um exemplo bem básico de como poderia ficar usando `Thread` (já da maneira mais moderna de como trabalhar com threads em python, através do módulo [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)).

**ATENÇÃO O EXEMPLO FOI ESCRITO UTILIZANDO PYTHON 3**

```
import re
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

import requests


HEADERS = {
    'user-agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}

MAX_WORKERS = 4


def featch_url(url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    except:
        return url, ''
    return url, res.text


def process_urls(urls):
    result = {}
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(featch_url, url) for url in urls]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        url, html = future.result()
        result[url] = html
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['http://www.pudim.com.br/']
    crawled = set()
    while urls:
        to_process = {url for url in urls if url not in crawled}
        print('start process urls: ', to_process)
        process_result = process_urls(to_process)
        urls = []
        for url, page in process_result.items():
            crawled.add(url)
            urls += re.findall(r'(?<=href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', page)

    print('Crawled pages: ', crawled)
```

O destaque do exemplo fica por conta da função `process_urls` que fica responsável por criar o `ThreadPoolExecutor` e "disparar" as threads.
Obviamente o exemplo deverá ser adaptado para a sua necessidade, pois da forma como está ele só irá percorrer todos os links que for encontrado pela frente e por fim vai adicionando no set `crawled` as páginas que já foram processadas.

Algumas observações

- No `MAX_WORKERS`(que consiste no número máximo de threads que serão abertas por vez) usei um número completamente arbitrário, porém a boa prática é usar o numero de CPUs da máquina * 2 (pode ser obtido via `os.cpu_count() * 2`)
- Caso você pense em fazer algum processamento em cada url (e não só pegar os links) você pode fazer dentro do for do `as_completed`, pois você consegue já ir processando as páginas conforme elas forem lidas e não somente quando todas forem lidas (isso lhe trara mais performance).
- Antes de trabalhar com Threads, tente entender os efeitos colaterais disso, ou seja, pesquise sobre *race conditions*, *locks*, etcs.

Apesar de ter feito o exemplo com thread (a nível de estudo/aprendizado) recomendo que caso seja necessário uma solução mais robusta de crawler, você de uma olhada no [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) e evite de reinventar a roda (a não ser que seja para apreender como as rodas funcionam).

Comment: Vou estudar o código, testar e te retorno depois. Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado @drgarcia1986. O programa é apenas para estudos!

Comment: a legal, então acho que vai ajudar :)
se tiver alguma dúvida ou problema é só falar

Comment: Obrigado. Em breve, te retorno.

Comment: criei um outro tópico com assunto semelhante num outro projeto, pois tenho dificuldade com o uso de Threads.